# Injecting json object property into an anchor's href attribute using the Play! Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, playframework

I have a jQuery ajax call that looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
       type     : 'GET',
       dataType : 'json',
       url      : '/Zoo/animals',
       success  : function(data){
           var count = data.length;               
           for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
               ${'#tableBody').append('<tr><td>');
               ${'#tableBody').append('<a href="@{Animal.index(data[i].name)}">' + data[i].name + '</a>');
               ${'#tableBody').append('</td></tr>');
           }
       }
    })
```

Now all of this works fine except for the `href` attribute.  Play! gives me the following error:

```
Exception raised was NullPointerException : Cannot get property 'name' on null object.
```

The json string that gets returned from the ajax call is fine as the text of the link shows up as the name of the animal as expected.  I would like to pass the name of the animal to the `Animal.index` action however have been unable to do so.

**Update:**

As others have mentioned, I have also tried this:

```
${'#tableBody').append('<a href="@{Animal.index(' + data[i].name + ')}">' + data[i].name + '</a>');
```

which just results in the link of:

```
localhost:9000/animal/index?name=+%2B+data[i].name+%2B+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Play! generates the url when the file is served, well before any javascript is executed. No change to the string or quotes here or there is going to help you.

A workaround:

```
var url = "@{Animal.index(XXX)}".replace('XXX', data[i].name);
${'#tableBody').append('<a href="'+url+'">' + data[i].name + '</a>');
```

This allows Play! to generate its url at "compile" time, and then javascript simply executes a replace at "run" time. Not sure if Play! will look for a variable named XXX, if so, add a dumby variable named XXX with value "XXX" on the server side.

**UPDATE**

I don't have a Play! instance in front of me to fiddle with, but instead of a variable, you could probably also insert the string directly as a value by quoting the XXX:

```
var url = '@{Animal.index("XXX")}'.replace('XXX', data[i].name);
```

And then you wouldn't need a variable named XXX. The details require a bit of playing around, although the idea is the same.

Comment: Unless I did something wrong, I tried the solution and it didn't make much of a difference.  The href url is resolved minus the data[i].name.  So the link works (as do the other solutions) but there is no query string.

Comment: @digiarnie, there should be a query string with XXX in it, which will be replaced by javascript on the fly. You understand the fundamental difference between my answer and the others right?

Comment: yep, I looked and thought about it a more and yeah, very clever indeed.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for the [`jsAction` tag](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/tags#jsaction). It generates a javascript function which works along the same lines as davin's answer.

You would put `var animalAction = #{jsAction @Animals.index(':name') /};` somewhere before your ajax call, then change your link generation code to:

```
${'#tableBody').append('<tr><td>');
${'#tableBody').append('<a href="' + animalAction({ name: data[i].name }) + '">' + data[i].name + '</a>');
${'#tableBody').append('</td></tr>');
```

You'll notice the generated function takes an object as it's argument, so it can support as many parameters as you want.

What isn't explicitly clear in the docs is that the label (`:name`) must be the same as the name of the parameter in the corresponding controller action (`public static void index(String name)`), which of course must be the same as how it's specified in the `routes` file (`GET /animals/{name} Animals.index`).

Answer (score 0):

data is a javascript object, you need to specify that similar to how you are printing the text of the link. Can you try this?

```
 ${'#tableBody').append('<a href="@{Animal.index(' + data.name + ')}">' + data.name + '</a>');
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I have tried that already as well.  In that case, Play! resolves the link to be: http://localhost:9000/animal/index?name=+%2B+data.name+%2B+

Comment: There is a difference in what you updated and what I had in my answer. I had passed data.name as a value to be concatenated to the string, but your updated post is different. You are not closing the string literal before concatenating data.name.

Answer (score 0):

you should change this line-

```
${'#tableBody').append('<a href="@{Animal.index(data[i].name)}">' + data[i].name + '</a>');
```

to this-

```
${'#tableBody').append('<a href="@{Animal.index('+data[i].name+')}">' + data[i].name + '</a>');
```

Comment: you should use single quote, not double.see in my answer and compare it with your post..you will get the difference.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo on my behalf, I actually have single quotes in my IDE. i.e. it looks like this: ${'#tableBody').append('<a href="@{Animal.index(' + data.name + ')}">' + data.name + '</a>');

Comment: in your link you have used `data[i].name` one more time as a query string, i just wnat to know that, are you getting correct value at this point?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking.  But according to firebug and the actual text value of the link, it all shows up as being the correct value I want to appear as the query link after the Play! Framework does its url resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over `data` array but you need to reference each data object by the index `i` so like `data[i]`. I would try this:

```
$.each(data, function(k, item) {
    $('#tableBody').append('<tr><td><a href="@{Animal.index(' + item.name + ')}">' + item.name + '</a></td></tr>');
});
```

This will replace everything inside your success callback

Comment: oops, that was my bad production code to stackoverflow code translation.  I indeed have it indexed correctly in my production code.

Comment: do a `console.log(data);` statement? just curious what does your `data` object look like

Comment: according to firebug 'data' looks like this: [{"name":"bob1"},{"name":"bob2"}]